# PHP crawling data from website

Tags: php, mysql, performance, web-crawler

I am currently trying to crawl alot of data from a website, however I am struggling a little bit with it. It has an a-z index and 1-20 index, so it has a bunch of loops and DOM stuff in there. However, it managed to crawl and save about 10.000 rows at first run, but now I am at around 15.000 and it is only crawling around 100 per run.

It is probably because it has to skip the rows that it already has inserted, (made a check for that). I cant think of a way to easily skip some pages, as the 1-20 index varies a lot (for one letter there are 18 pages, other letter are only 2 pages).

I was checking if there already was an record with the given ID, if not, insert it. I assumed that would be slow, so now before the script stars I retrieve all rows, and then check with an in_array(), assuming thats faster. But it just wont work.

So my crawler is navigating 26 letters, 20 pages each letter, and then up to 50 times each page, so if you calculate it, its a lot.

Thought of running it letter by letter, but that wont really work as I am still stuck at "a" and cant just hop onto "b" as I will miss records from "a".

Hope I have explained the problem good enough for someone to help me. My code kinda looks like this: (I have removed some stuff here and there, guess all the important stuff is in here to give you an idea)

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
/* CONNECT TO DB */
mysql_connect()......



$qry = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM tableName");
$all = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qru)) {
    $all[] = $row;
} // Retrieving all the current database rows to compare later

foreach (range("a", "z") as $key) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $dom = new DomDocument();
        $dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.crawleddomain.com/".$i."/".$key.".htm");
        $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
        $classname="table-striped";
        $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $rows = $finder->query("//a[contains(@href, '/value')]", $node);
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $url = $row->getAttribute("href");
                $dom2 = new DomDocument();
                $dom2->loadHTMLFile("http://www.crawleddomain.com".$url);
                $finder2 = new DomXPath($dom2);
                $classname2="table-striped";
                $nodes2 = $finder2->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname2 ')]");
                foreach ($nodes2 as $node2) {

                    $rows2 = $finder2->query("//a[contains(@href, '/loremipsum')]", $node2);
                    foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {

                        $dom3 = new DomDocument();
                        //
                        // not so important variable declarations..
                        //


                        $dom3->loadHTMLFile("http://www.crawleddomain.com".$url);
                        $finder3 = new DomXPath($dom3);
                        //2 $finder3->query() right here


                        $query231 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE uid='$uid'");
                        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query231);
                        //Doing this to get category ID from another table, to insert with this row..
                        $id = $result['id'];


                        if (!in_array_r($uid, $all)) { // if not exist
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO')"); // insert the whole bunch
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `$uid` defined?

Comment: Create a unique index on `uid` and then do your inserts to db with `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE` let db to do the hard job.

Comment: I cant use that, as uid can be the same, as the title can exist in other categories. I cant combine those, as they are completely different articles but with just the same name. Found that solution, but isnt the solution for me, too bad...

Answer (score 1):

`$uid` is not defined, also, this query makes no sense:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO')");
```

You should turn on error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

After your queries you should do an `or die(mysql_error());`

Also, I might as well say it, if I don't someone else will. Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Try [PDO](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: As I have said, I have removed stuff like useless variable declarations and shortened some queries. They are all working and intact. As this has to do everything with the amount of queries and the crawling, I thought it was useless to keep all the code. Don't worry, the paths are working and all variables are defined.

Comment: Ok, but still, `INSERT INTO')` is not a proper query.

Comment: @Adelphia He removed some code to create a small example.

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar you should update your question with your most recent code if you want a helpful answer, you know? ;)

Comment: Ok, but STILL, unless he removed half his query for some reason, that's still not a valid query and there's no debugging done in the visible code.

Comment: What debugging should've been done in here? The code is working, its just optimizing that probably needs to be done. If I knew how to optimize it, I wouldnt ask here. @Oerd, this is the most recent code, without the useless stuff. It doesnt matter for you guys what my query looks like, you just need to know its there

Comment: I am aware of mysql_ being deprecated, its just for ease and this code is one time use only. So I am fine with using mysql_* functions here. Also, error reporting was on and no errors besides some html warnings from the url that is being crawled, but those are just warnings and no errors. Code works fine, dont forget that with this code I already crawled 10k+ rows.

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar you might be right, but then again: if it doesn't matter, why should we spend those minutes to read your question at all? This attitude is just wrong towards someone trying to help you out.

Comment: I dont really get your point? All I have done is shortening my code so it would be more straight to the point and it should save you time reading it.

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar I happened to have a script that does exactly the same thing. I wrote it for the marketing department at my company for gathering emails. The only difference is that it saves the data to session instead of MySQL, then you can have it upload the data directly to SQL if necessary. I'll be gladd to zip it up and send it your way if you'd like to try it. PM me.

Comment: @Adelphia There is no way to PM on stackoverflow. Any other way you can share it? Perhaps pastebin it, or add it on github? Cheers! Does your script handle that much pages aswell? I think this script would handle around 300k-500k pages in total. I have tried this code with less pages (this goes like 4 pages deep aswell, homepage -> category page -> category detail -> post detail) and it worked with just one layer of pages for about 50k rows.

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar go to https://www.guerrillamail.com and paste your email into the comments, I'll attach it and send it.

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar just sent it. Just unzip it to your site and open crawler/ all the guts are located in crawler/res/brain, if you have make chages that's probably where you'll want to look.